# Accounting for tiebreakers in the longest of three words array

Tags: javascript

```
function getLongestOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {
  
  word1 = word1.split(' ');
  word2 = word2.split(' ');
  word3 = word3.split(' ');

  var newArr = word1.concat(word2,word3);
  var LongestWord = [];
  var LongestWordLength = 0;

  for(var i=0; i<newArr.length; i++) {
    if(newArr[i].length > LongestWordLength) {
      longestWord = newArr[i];
      longestWordLength = newArr[i].length;
    }
  }

  return longestWord;
}

var output = getLongestOfThreeWords('these', 'three', 'words');
console.log(output); // --> 'these'
```

Got a problem I can't seem to figure out, for a longest of three words function -

"If there is a tie, it should return the first word in the tie."

Presently I'm only returning 'words', when 'these should be returned. This doesn't make sense to me because longestWordLength = newArr[i].length; Any help on this?

Comment: If it's a *word* than could you explain why you use `.split(" ")`

Comment: I'm converting the string elements into an array. that way I can concat to add them together. From that point I can run a for loop and find the items with the longest length

Comment: Ok after your comment I realized I can do that a lot easier. I was looking at things from the wrong angle. Thanks for helping me realize that

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLongestOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {
  if(word1.length >= word2.length && word3.length) {
    return word1;
  } else if (word2.length > word3.length && word1.length) {
    return word2;
  } else {
    return word3;
  }
}

var output = getLongestOfThreeWords('these', 'three', 'words');
console.log(output); // --> 'these'
```

Answer (score 0):

Great you figured out a solution.
You current solution though still is limited to three arguments only, if you want something more flexible use [**Rest Parameters**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
const getLongest = (...words) => words.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];

console.log(getLongest('these', 'words', 'three'));          // these
console.log(getLongest('super'));                            // super
console.log(getLongest('nice', 'and', 'super', 'flexible')); // flexible
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach:

1. Put words in `newArr`
2. Iterate over the array, if the current item's `length` is greater than `longestWordLength`, do the updates

Note: you're updating different variables that you defined at first

```js
function getLongestOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {
  const newArr = [word1, word2, word3];
  let longestWord = undefined;
  let longestWordLength = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    if(newArr[i].length > longestWordLength) {
      longestWord = newArr[i];
      longestWordLength = newArr[i].length;
    }
  }

  return longestWord;
}

const output = getLongestOfThreeWords('these', 'three', 'words');
console.log(output);
```

Your other approach with the correct conditions:

```js
function getLongestOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {
  if(word1.length >= word2.length && word1.length >= word3.length) {
    return word1;
  } else if (word2.length >= word3.length) {
    return word2;
  } else {
    return word3;
  }
}

const output = getLongestOfThreeWords('these', 'three', 'words');
console.log(output);
```